# mail utility wont send to my cellphone?

Tags: command-line, email, mail

Im writing a script, and I want it to alert me via text message. I can send my self texts via things like gmail using: "number@vtext.com", and I can send emails to gmail using the `mail` command, but when I try to get my script to send me a text message, I never get it, I'm not sure why.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -vx
m="The cookie jar is open."
s="Give me a cookie"
id="@vtext.com"
num="0000000000"    #fake number for this post.
echo -e $m | mail -s $s  $num$id
```

How can I send sms to my cellphone? what am I doing wrong?

my carrier is verison.

Comment: If you have your system able to send via command line setup like https://linode.com/docs/email/postfix/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/ then you might be missing quotes like `echo -e "$m" | mail -s "$s" $num$id`  I don't think the `-e` is needed.  I send from my scripts and I don't have the `-e`.

Comment: -e was for something else not included, but I don't think it should hurt the overall functionality either. Ill give your recommendation a try, thanks or looking.

Comment: The system running this, is this on a Residential connection, or is it a dedicated server like a VPS?  Most residential ISPs are 'blacklisted' for email sources, and aren't permitted to send emails out as an SMTP / Mail Origin point.  (unless it's routed over GMail or a third-party server which actually handles the sending of the message to the destination 'address')

Comment: Also, have you tested that command yourself, outside of a script, to make sure it works as you intend it to?

Comment: yes, this is a residential conection, and I have tested the script it works for email, like user@gmail.com, but not for: phone-number@vtext.com. I have tested this every way I can think of, and now I am online asking for help.

Comment: @j0h Have you tried to send something to your phone by using your GMail Web App?

Comment: @Terrance, yes, I have sent sms via number@vtext.com to my phone via gmail, and that works.

Comment: Check your `/var/log/mail.log` when you try to send.  It might help pinpoint more of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If using gmail you will have to enable "less secure apps" as done here
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

I ran across the same problem in windows using CDO.Message and had to inform gmail that I was using "less secure apps" before my text message would work.